# .NET MAUI how to RESTful API POST and get back response

Tags: c#, rest, maui, dotnet-httpclient

This is a RESTful API question, and my lack of experience and knowledge with this subject will probably force me to use bad terminology / say dumb stuff, so I apologize in advance.

### What I'm trying to do

User enters a username and password.  I use a RESTful API to GET account information, with the username as one of the args.  If I get back information from the GET, then the user exists.  Then I can look at the password (that's part of the information that I get back).  If it matches what the user put in, great.  We continue on with the Android app.

This isn't the problem.

The problem is that in order to do the GET, I need an "access_token", a long string.  To get this string, I need to do a POST that creates this "access_token" resource and returns it to me.

I can find some code examples and explanations on how to do this, but I can't find ones that are complete.  For example, this image is from a [Microsoft demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxImRQEWe_w) (around the 25 minute mark):

[image]

This looks like exactly what I need!  Except for one problem:  I have **no idea** what this line of code means/does:

```
message.Content = JsonContent.Create<Part>(part);
```

That's not entirely true.  I can Google "[JsonContent.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.json.jsoncontent.create?view=net-7.0)" as well as the next person, but I don't know how to create an object of type `Part` or how to come up with the argument "part" (I don't even know what it is). Frankly, the docs that I read about `HttpRequestMessage` and `JsonContent` are a little over my head, and lack actual code examples.

### I can run the POST on Postman

I'm assuming that the object `Part` from the code above is some class that contains the arguments that I need for the POST.

I'm also assuming that I can find these arguments when I run the POST on Postman (which was given to me by a colleague).  When I run the POST on Postman, there are a few sections, right?

The URI, Params, Authorization, Headers, Body, etc..., and the response.  In this case, the only sections that have values are the URI (of course), Headers, and Body.

**Headers**
I think the values in the Headers are specific to Postman, so I probably don't need to add these to some object called "Part" (or whatever it is that I need to do):
[image]

**Body**
It's here where there are a lot of values that are needed.  If I uncheck any of these values, I get the ol' `400 Bad Request` response when I run the POST:

[image]

**Response**
And here's the response from the POST.  This is what I'd like to get back as the `HttpResponseMessage` from the C# code snippet posted above:

[image]

### With all that said, what's my question?

Am I correct in assuming that I need to create some object/class in my Maui project that represents the information from the **Body** pic above?  Like, that's what I need to put here?
[image]

If the answer is "yes", is there somewhere that explains what I need to do in step-by-step terms with code examples?  Hopefully with words like "for beginners" or "for dummies" or "for Golden Retrievers" in the title?  (It's hard to over-emphasize how little I know.)

If the answer is "no", then... well, I need to learn how to to a POST in Maui that gets a response as well, and I can't find anywhere that explains how to do it.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%2523+httpclient+post+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: This example leads me to the same question.  The argument "bodyObject" is passed into the argument `string requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bodyObject);`.  What is this?  And what's the equivalent line of code from my question?

Comment: (With that said, I don't know how I missed this example.  My Googling skills are terrible.  Of course, I've been searching using "Maui" not "ASP.NET".  Maybe that's what it is.)

Comment: it's really a general .NET question

Comment: if its a simple GET you would just pass any arguments on the querystring, not in the body.

Comment: It's a POST, as I have to create the resource as well as get it back.

Comment: then you need to include the json serialized object in the body

Comment: OK, I just looked up how to create a Json Serialized Object.  Seems easy enough.  Then I should initialize the serialized object and use it like this:  `message.Content = JsonContent.Create<SerializedObject>(serializedObject)`.  OK!  I'll give that a shot!

Comment: `HttpClient` has a `Post` method that takes a path and a content object

Comment: And the "content object" is the serialized object?  (I don't know the terminology.)

Answer (score 0):

You would probably find more working examples with Xamarin, or just plain C#, in general the principles are similar.

Your REST API is passing data in JSON format, hence the easiest thing is to have classes for the data that you pass and receive.
With the help of Newtonsoft.Json package (install it in you solution) you can easily serialize and deserialize your classes when passing or receiving data.

Thus for your Login parameters and response you could have:

```
public class LoginParams
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Unique user reference
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("username")]
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string UserReference { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Password used by user
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

and one for the response:

```
public class LoginResponse
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     Authorization token for a successful login
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    [SoapAttribute(AttributeName = "Token")]
    public string AuthorizationToken { get; set; }  

    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public string LifeSpan {get;set;}

    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType {get;set;}

    /// <summary>
    ///     Token to be used for authorization token refresh
    /// </summary>
    [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
    [SoapAttribute(AttributeName = "RefreshToken")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }  
}
```

Then you'd have something like:

```
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var loginParams = new LoginParams() { UserReference = userReference, Password = password };
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(loginParams),Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        HttpResponseMessage  response = await httpClient.PostAsync($@"ServerURL}/auth/login", content);

        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {        
            // add some code to handle this
            return;
        }
        

        var authorization = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LoginResponse>(responseContent);
```

This isn't fully prepared code, it's just a pointer, there's no `try ... catch` block around the API calls and you may wish to handle the asynchronous nature a little better, especially for error conditions.

As well as NewtonSoft you may wish to look at other nuget packages that can help simplify this for you.

Comment: Chris, I will try this as soon as I figure out an exception that I am getting.  `{Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid input to toASCII: site03_identity.vlxdemo.com
 ---> Android.Icu.Text.StringPrepParseException: The input does not conform to the STD 3 ASCII rules`  I think it has something to do with there being underscores in the URL that I'm attempting to connect with.

Comment: Which line of code is reporting this error?